# Get all contents between the result tags of a SOAP response in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I have this SOAP response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetCurrencyCodeByCurrencyNameResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
        <GetCurrencyCodeByCurrencyNameResult>
             &lt;NewDataSet /&gt;
        </GetCurrencyCodeByCurrencyNameResult>
    </GetCurrencyCodeByCurrencyNameResponse>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And I use this code to get the contents of the result tag:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(SoapResponse) 
child=root[0][0][0]
contenu= child.text
```

But when I have a response which contains other tags inside the results tag (other children) like this SOAP response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetUserInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetUserInfoResult>
                <ErrorOccured>true</ErrorOccured>
                <ErrorStr>System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4CuTrO8O6Tn' to data type int.
                          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
                          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()
                          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
                          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
                          at Service.GetUserInfo(String username, String password)
                </ErrorStr>
                <SqlQuery>SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=''+(select convert(int,CHAR(52)+CHAR(67)+CHAR(117)+CHAR(84)+CHAR(114)+CHAR(79)+CHAR(56)+CHAR(79)+CHAR(54)+CHAR(84)+CHAR(110)) FROM syscolumns)+'' AND password='32cc5886dc1fa8c106a02056292c4654'
                </SqlQuery><id>-1</id><joindate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</joindate>
            </GetUserInfoResult>
        </GetUserInfoResponse>
    </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I can not get the contents between result tags with the previous code.
So, how can I get the whole contents between the result tags of a SOAP response ?

Comment: 1) What are you calling the "result tags"? I don't see any tags named "result". 2) In what form do you want the "whole contents"? An XML fragment? An ET element?

Comment: The result tag of a SOAP response is  root[0][0][0] named <nameOfmethodResult>. Because I have a lot of SOAP responses to analyze, I dont have the names of all methods so I use root[0][0][0] to get the element that I need. 
For the form, i need an XML fragment or a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on exactly what you want, but this might do it:

```
# This gets all of the text data in the indicated region
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(SoapResponse)
child=root[0][0][0]
contenu = ET.tostring(child, encoding='UTF-8', method='text').decode('UTF-8')
```

Or

```
# This gets the indicated XML fragment as a string
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(SoapResponse)
child=root[0][0][0]
contenu = ET.tostring(child, encoding='UTF-8', method='xml')
```

Comment: Using `contenu = ET.tostring(child, encoding='UTF-8', method='text').decode('UTF-8')` I get only text but I want to get exactly the contents between  <GetUserInfoResult> and </GetUserInfoResult> (all the XML fragment )

Comment: In that case, you want the same call, but with `method='xml'`. See my edit. Of course, if you intend to do further analysis of the result, if might be easier just to use `child`.